# PHP: Can a Single Function execute multiple Commands?

Tags: php, wordpress, ads

I use this code snippet to insert Ads after the third paragraph and it works just fine.

```
//Insert ads after third paragraph
add_filter( 'the_content', 'third_paragraph_ads' );
function third_paragraph_ads ( $content ) {
    $ad_code1 = 'AD CODE HERE';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return insert_third_paragraph_ads( $ad_code1, 3, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

// Parent Function for third paragraph Ads
function insert_third_paragraph_ads( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

But How can I insert Ads after paragraphs 3, 6, and 9 with this same function?

Something like this would give you a better idea of the question (neither works nor makes sense though):

```
//Insert ads after third paragraph
add_filter( 'the_content', 'third_paragraph_ads' );
function third_paragraph_ads ( $content ) {
    $ad_code1 = 'AD CODE HERE1';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return insert_third_paragraph_ads( $ad_code1, 3, $content );
    }
$ad_code2 = 'AD CODE HERE2';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return insert_third_paragraph_ads( $ad_code1, 6, $content );
    }
    $ad_code3 = 'AD CODE HERE3';
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        return insert_third_paragraph_ads( $ad_code1, 9, $content );
    }
    return $content;
}

// Parent Function for third paragraph Ads
function insert_third_paragraph_ads( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and thought to share the solution should anyone else be confronted with the same challenge:

```
//Insert ads after third paragraph
add_filter( 'the_content', 'third_paragraph_ads' );
function third_paragraph_ads ( $content ) {
    $ad_code = 'Ads code 1';
    $ad_code2 = 'Ads code 2';
    $ad_code3 = 'Ads code 3';
        if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
            $content = insert_third_paragraph_ads( $ad_code, 2, $content );
            $content = insert_third_paragraph_ads( $ad_code2, 6, $content );
            $content = insert_third_paragraph_ads( $ad_code3, 8, $content );
                return $content;
            }
            return $content;
}

// Parent Function for third paragraph Ads
function insert_third_paragraph_ads( $insertion, $paragraph_id, $content ) {
    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );
    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }
        if ( $paragraph_id == $index + 1 ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $insertion;
        }
    }
    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}
```